# How to use the SimpleJdbcTemplate queryForMap

Tags: java, sql, spring, ibatis

Is there a way to get a `Map<String,Integer>` for instance? The call seems to return only a `Map<String, Object>` which I can't cast to `Map<String,Integer>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use it like this:

```
Map result = simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForMap(
 "SELECT COUNT(*) AS intRecords " +
 "FROM tblUsers",
 new Object[]);

Integer users = result.get("intRecords");
```

Does that help you?